# Proof $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}n(a^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)=\log a$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, logarithms, radicals

I want to show that for all $a \in \mathbb{R }$

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n(a^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)=\log a$$

So far I've got $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}ne^{(\frac{1}{n}\log a)}-n$, but when i go on to rearrange this, i come  after a few steps back to the beginning...

We have no L'Hôpital and no differential and integral calculus so far.

Comment: What is your definition of $\log a$ without differential or integral calculus?

Comment: $\log := \exp ^{-1}$

Comment: What is your definition of $\exp$ then? Usually one needs a bit of differential/integral calculus to define these functions formally.

Comment: $\exp:=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$

Comment: How is that not calculus?

Comment: Write out the first few terms of that sum with $x = \frac{1}{n} \ln(a)$ and see what happens when you multiply the whole sum by $n$, then subtract $n$ and take $n \to \infty$.

Comment: If $a < 0$, $a^{1/n}$ is complex for even $n$.

Comment: By the way this limit can be used as a definition of $\log a$. I also admit that it is not as simple as the the integral of $1/x$ over $[1, a]$, but proving elementary properties like $\log ab = \log a + \log b$ and increasing nature of $\log$ are easily done with this definition.

Comment: $f(a) = \lim_{n \to \infty} n(a^{1/n}-1) = \lim_{n / x \to \infty} n/ x(a^{x/n}-1) = f(a^x)/x$ thus  it is a logarithm : $f(a) = C \ln a$. but proving $C=1$ is more difficult, you have to use one of the specific properties of $\ln$ or $\exp$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x = 1/n$. Then you want the limit of 
$$
\frac{a^x-1}{x} = \frac{e^{x \log(a)} - 1}{x} = \frac{1 + x \log(a) + R(x \log a) -1}{x}
= \log (a) + \log a \left[\frac{R(x \log a)}{x \log a} \right] $$

Now

$$ \frac{R(x \log a)}{x \log a} \rightarrow 0 \text { as } x\rightarrow 0$$

Where I have used the fact that $$e^{\theta} = 1 + \theta + R(\theta),
~~~ \text { and } \lim_{\theta->0} \frac{R(\theta)}{\theta} = 0$$

Here $R(\theta)$ is
$$
R(\theta)  = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\theta^k}{k!}$$

Comment: My work assumes that $a \neq 1$. If $a=1$ the result is obvious.

Comment: Where did you get that $R$?

Comment: R is the rest of the summation. Let me edit my answer

Comment: And why is $e^{x \log(a) - 1}=1 + x \log(a) + R(x \log a) -1$?

Comment: There is a little typo in the exponent. It's supposed to be $e^{x \log a} - 1$, not $e^{x \log a - 1}$. Other than that it's just your definition of $e^\theta$.

Comment: Let me fix it! hate to leave mistakes uncorrected

Comment: You can use `\to` to get an arrow like this $\to$. It looks better than $->$ which appear in your limit.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially the inverse of
$$
e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n
$$
The sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ converge equicontinuously; simply note that $f_n'(x)=\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{n-1}\sim e^x$. Thus, we get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(e^{x/n}-1\right)=x
$$
which is the same as
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(x^{1/n}-1\right)=\log(x)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to notice that this is a definition of derivative (if you are allowed to use it):
$$
\lim_{v \to 0}\frac{a^v-1}{v} = a^v \log a\Bigg|_{v=0}=\log a
$$